# Get the data of a form containing inputs with different names

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm using a form of formstack(a website that create dynamic forms), but the problem is that formstack generate inputs with "randoms" names (all the names are field+numbers). So I can't save the answers in my system.

Here are a little part of the code of the form.

```
<form method="post" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../../funciones/borrar.php" class="fsForm fsSingleColumn fsMaxCol1" id="fsForm2779461">

<div class="fsSection fs1Col fsHidden" id="fsSection55289049">
<div class="fsSectionHeader">
<h2 class="fsSectionHeading">Adopción</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="fsSection fs1Col fsHidden" id="fsSection55287407">
<div class="fsSectionHeader">
<h2 class="fsSectionHeading">Demandas de violencia intrafamiliar</h2>
</div>
<div id="fsRow2779461-4" class="fsRow fsFieldRow fsLastRow">
<div class="fsRowBody fsCell fsFieldCell fsFirst fsLast fsLabelVertical fsSpan100" id="fsCell55287595" lang="es">
<label id="label55287595" class="fsLabel" for="field55287595">¿Es usted el demandante o el demandado? </label>
<select id="field55287595" name="field55287595" size="1" class="fsField" disabled="disabled">
<option value="Seleccione una respuesta">Seleccione una respuesta</option>
<option value="Demandante">Demandante</option>
<option value="Demandado">Demandado</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div id="fsRow2779461-5" class="fsRow fsFieldRow fsLastRow fsHidden">
<div class="fsRowBody fsCell fsFieldCell fsFirst fsLast fsLabelVertical fsHidden fsSpan100" id="fsCell55287612" lang="es">
<label id="label55287612" class="fsLabel" for="field55287612">¿Hizo constatación de lesiones?                    </label>
<select id="field55287612" name="field55287612" size="1" class="fsField" disabled="disabled">
<option value="Seleccione una respuesta">Seleccione una respuesta</option>
<option value="Si">Si</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

and here I get the answer of the first field

```
<?php
$preguntas=$_POST["field55287595"];

echo $preguntas;
?>
```

I can't do the same method putting all the fields because they are more than 200 inputs.
There are a way to save all the answers in a array or something like that?

Comment: `$_POST` already is an array containing all the answers. If you want to save it in a database you may `serialize` or `json_encode` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo "Answer key ==> ".htmlspecialchars($key)." value ==>   ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
}
```

`$_POST` variable contains all post values. If there is get method you can use `$_GET.` And for Both you can use `$_REQUEST;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the php foreach loop like this

```
foreach ($_POST as $field => $value){

//do something 

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what you need to do.